# Error when instantiating class: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a class here:

```
export class MyClass {
    public name:string;
    public addr:string;

    constructor() {}
}
```

And I import it here:

```
import { MyClass } from './MyClass';

// and use it here:

class MyUser {
    private _prop : MyClass[];

    constructor() {
        this._prop = [
            new MyClass({name: 'Hello', addr: 'World'}) //<--- this is where the error appears
        ]
    }
}
```

When I do this I get a linting error:

```
Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
```

Why can't I instantiate my class?

Comment: Looks like you are expecting Typescript to have object initialize abilities like C# does. But Typescript does not have that :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't had mention any parameter in your MyClass constructor. You have to put parameter in constructor so that you can set value while instantiating this class. You could move `MyClass` properties to constructor `parameter` to make it shortened syntax like below.

```
export class MyClass {
    //by having `public` on constructor shortened the syntax.
    constructor(public name: string, public addr:string) {

    }
}   

constructor() {
    this._prop = [
        new MyClass('Hello', 'World')
    ]
}
```

[**Playground Demo**](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=module%20Entities%20%7B%20%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20MyClass%20%7B%0A%0A%09%09constructor(public%20name%3A%20string%2C%20public%20addr%3Astring)%20%7B%0A%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%09export%20class%20MyUser%20%7B%0A%09%09private%20_prop%20%3A%20MyClass%5B%5D%3B%0A%09%0A%09%09constructor()%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this._prop%20%3D%20%5B%0A%09%09%09%09new%20MyClass('Hello'%2C%20'World')%20%2F%2F%3C---%20this%20is%20where%20the%20error%20appears%0A%09%09%09%5D%0A%09%09%09console.log(this._prop)%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%09%0A%09var%20a%20%3D%20new%20MyUser()%3B%0A%7D)

Answer (score 1):

You should have the following for your constructor. In your case, you defined no parameters:

```
constructor(param:{name:string, addr:string}) {
  this.name = param.name;
  this.addr = param.addr;
}
```

Another option would be to define your class properties at the level of your constructor:

```
constructor(public name:string, public addr:string) {
  // No need for this:
  // this.name = name;
  // this.addr = addr;
}
```

You can now pass parameter to your constructor and they'll use to initialize your instance properties:

```
constructor() {
  this._prop = [
    new MyClass('Hello', 'World'})
  ];
}
```